# Name does not appear in top right corner in iCloud and incorrect time zone is set

Tags: icloud, calendar

The times in my iCloud calendar are all wrong.

The answer I found to fix this is to click on my name in top right hand corner — only problem is that my name does not appear there and I can find nowhere to access settings for the time zone.

iCould currently shows "Pacific time zone" and I need it to be set to "Australian Eastern Summer time".

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you missed a step on the answer you were looking at - you should be doing this on the iCloud site, not in iCal.

Goto [iCloud.com](https://icloud.com), log in, then you should see your name in the top right corner:
[image]

Click there, and you should get an account preferences pop-up where you can set your time zone info:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can log into iCloud.com and go to the iCloud start page by clicking on the cloud icon in the top left corner of your screen. iCloud will remember the last web page you visited and it won't bring you to the start page on startup.

Once you are in the start page, you can click on your account name in the top right corner of the screen. That brings up a dialog box where you can specify your iCloud account's time zone. Hope this helps.